# How to improve my regression problem having a low accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I want to solve a small regression problem.
My dataset consists of two features:

- the population of a country
- the number of representatives

So, my objective is: given the population of a country I get the estimated number of representative. The issue is that the using linear regression I get a 50% of accuracy.
Can this be be motivated by the distribution of the data?
Here some descriptors of the dataset:
[image]
And here my scatter plot:
[image]

I am new in ML and I'm trying to do some stuff by myself. How can I improve my model? I was thinking:

- use a non linear regression to better fit the data
- improve my dataset (e.g. removing outliers)

Comment: Please **re-read** [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that asking for external resources is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Your thoughts are right. And also try to standardized data before inputting to the model.

Answer (score 1):

Your data isn't compatible with linear regression (at least when trying to apply OLS) since you are seeing an aggresive [heteroskedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity) in the chart you have attached. There are some techniques that can assist you achieve better results such as performing the linear regression with robust standard error calculation.

Since you are new to ML and probably trying to perform the regression in order to get better, I'd suggest focusing merely in the records that are a part of the dense group in the bottom left part of your chart. That way, you will avoid the problem I mentioned above. Furthermore, Linear regression tends to perform better around the mean value of each feature. Having many records with low variance would make this regression perform much better.

Next time I would suggest asking this kind of questions either in [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or in [Statistics Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Good luck!